# Upper bound of $(1+x)^n$ and lower bound of $(1-x)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality, binomial-theorem, upper-lower-bounds

Is there any generic lower bound of $(1-x)^n$ and upper bound of $(1+x)^n$, where $0<x<1$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: What do you mean by "generic"? Are you happy with an upper bound like $e^{n x}$, for instance?

Comment: @ClementC. The way that I interpret the problem, if $n$ is fixed, you can consider $(1)^n, ~(1 - 1)^n,~$ and $~(1 + 1)^n.$

Comment: For what it's worth, I posted an answer and then thought better of it, and deleted the answer.  Your posted problem represents a math problem to be attacked, rather than an interpretation question.  Therefore, it seems reasonable to ask you to improve the quality of your question before an answer is given.  See [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) if you are interested in improving the quality of your question.

Answer (score 0):

$(1-x)^n> 0^n=0$ for $0<x<1$. Moreover, for any $M>0$,
\begin{align}
(1+x)^n>M  \iff\\
n> \frac{\ln M}{\ln(1+x)}.
\end{align}
Of course, such an $n$ can always be chosen. It should be clear that $(1+x)^n$ is unbounded from above.